# Javascript date to C# via Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, date

I have javascript date object which gives me a date string in this format, "Wed Dec 16 00:00:00 UTC-0400 2009".

I pass this via Ajax to the server (ASP.NET c#)

How can I convert, "Wed Dec 16 00:00:00 UTC-0400 2009" to a C# DateTime object. DateTime.Parse fails.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) which allows you to specify a format string to be used for parsing:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Wed Dec 16 00:00:00 UTC-0400 2009",
                                  "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTCzzzzz yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You may want to use DateTimeOffset instead.

Answer (score 32):

The most reliable way would be to use milliseconds since the epoch. You can easily get this in JavaScript by calling `Date.getTime()`. Then, in C# you can convert it to a DateTime like this:

```
long msSinceEpoch = 1260402952906; // Value from Date.getTime() in JavaScript
return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddTicks(msSinceEpoch * 10000);
```

You have to multiply by 10,000 to convert from milliseconds to "ticks", which are 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: I know this is an old, old answer but I do have a question. Is there any particular reason you add a new TimeSpan instead of calling DateTime's `.AddMilliseconds` method?

Comment: No reason I can remember. I've edited the answer to use `AddTicks` now, which is probably marginally faster than `AddMilliseconds` (we're talking a few CPU cycles here).

Comment: I got curious about why the "epoch" is 1970/01/01.  It turns out this is the "Unix epoch."  I thought I'd share in case others are curious or confused: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Any reason not to just use DateTime.AddMilliseconds?

return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(msSinceEpoch);

Comment: I would recommend using Date.parse() in JavaScript (rather than Date.getTime()) - it gets the number of milliseconds since the epoch in local time.

Comment: Pay attention: JS Date.getTime returns the time in UTC. so if you want local time in C# you have to use ToLocalTime():
`return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddTicks(msSinceEpoch * 10000).ToLocalTime();`

Answer (score 22):

This may not be possible in your case, but I really recommend updating the JS code to pass dates/times in ISO 8601 format.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

**ISO 8601 is not only the formal standard, it's also easy to use and prevents a lot of timezone hassle!**

To get 8601 datetime strings in Javascript:

```
var d = new Date();
var iso_time = d.toISOString(); //"2014-05-06T18:49:16.029Z"
```

To read 8601 datetime strings in C#:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(json_string);
```

Comment: I see this as being the best approach because it's a single step and doesn't require jumping through any other hoops to handle the timezone or System.DateTime parsing.

Comment: I'm using this approach to conform to momentjs

Answer (score 5):

Just for posterity, to help future fellow Googlers, I'd like to expand on EMP's answer.

EMP's answer provides the time in **UTC** (if that's what you're looking for, use that).

To arrive at the **client local time** in C#:

In JavaScript:

```
        var now = new Date();
        var UTC = now.getTime();
        var localOffset = (-1) * now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
        var currentTime = Math.round(new Date(UTC + localOffset).getTime());
```

In C#:

```
        DateTime currentTimeDotNet = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddTicks(Convert.ToInt64(currentTime) * 10000);
```

Credit to [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/29/javascript-creating-timestamps-with-time-zone-offsets.aspx) and EMP's answer, but took some trial and error on both ends to get it right, so just fyi for future folks.

Comment: This is the most-correct answer that correctly handles time-zone adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I wouldn't try to parse that date string in C#, I'd personally try to create a more useful date structure from your javascript date object.

For instance you could use `parse()` in javascript which will return the ms representing the date object, which you can use `DateTime.Parse()` on to convert into a C# DateTime object.