# convert javascript time to asp.net DateTime.Now

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, datetime

I'm trying to convert the javascript date to ASP.NET's DateTime.Now

```
var todaysDate = new Date();
document.getElementById('hdnDate').value = todaysDate.toString();


private void ConvertToDotNetDateTime()
{
    DateTime myDate = (DateTime)hdnDate.Value; ??? ? //bit lost here
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877788/javascript-date-to-c-via-ajax

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('hdnDate').value = (new Date()).format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

in C#:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

string date = hfClientDate.Value;

string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, provider);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) to convert the date to DateTime.Now

You can check the [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: -1. A lot of your answers seem to be comprised of "check the link" and that is not the point of SO - especially when the same link was already posted as a comment 40 minutes earlier.