# Best way to convert JavaScript date to .NET date

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have a date in JavaScript and its value is coming like this

Fri Apr 01 2011 05:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}

Now what is the best way to convert the date to .NET date . Note that my client side users can be anwyehere around the world. I will have the date from there now my need is to convert it to the .NET date. can you help me ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Possible duplicate of the question answered here:
[Javascript date to C# via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877788/javascript-date-to-c-via-ajax)

If you want local time, like you are showing in your question the following would do it.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString.Substring(0,24),
                              "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you are looking for GMT time, doing a `dateObject.toUTCString()` in Javascript in the browser before you send it to the server, would do it.

Comment: +1 nice .. i was searching for exact format string but later abandoned that idea and chose AddMilliseconds. :)

Comment: @Rocky - editing the answer on how to make what you have work.

Comment: @shekhar - curious!  How did you do it with AddMilliseconds?

Comment: .. its in my answer.. but it is not Culture Invariant.. and is prone to TimeZone Errors :(

Comment: Above is not quite right.  Should be:  dateString.Substring(0,24)

Answer (score 14):

Convert JavaScript into UTCString from Client side:

```
var testDate = new Date().toUTCString();
```

Parse it from C# code (you can fetch js date through webservice call).

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(testDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your time to string before you send it and in the .net you should convert a string into datetime using one of datetime constructor.
Datetime .net -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=VS.90).aspx
You can use also a **DateTime.Parse** method -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx
But you should deliver a correct form of string to server

Answer (score 0):

Ok here try this simple function which will convert your `double' representation of your Unix Timestamp

```
public static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return origin.AddMilliseconds(timestamp); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Naraen's answer, my javascript date was in the following format:

```
Thu Jun 01 2017 04:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Which required two lower case d's for the day (`dd`) for the conversion to work for me in C#. See update to @Naraen's code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString.Substring(0,24),
                          "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```