# Dates - JavaScript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I hate dates, I can never get them to behave.
I have a javascript variable that looks like this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

I pass this to a C# Web API controller as a parameter.
My local time was 12:43 but when I put a breakpoint in my action it shows 11:43. The problem is, that if I do this at 00:43 then my controller would take the date as yesterday. I need it to pick out the right day. If I select the currentDate as 02/09/2015 12:43 then I need my controller to use the same date.

I know this has something to do with local times etc, but how can I get them all to use the same one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to do all your work with UTC dates.  I'm not sure about javascript, but .NET has that capability.

Comment: Yeah, I already use UTC dates with C# but the problem is what JavaScript is passing.

Comment: passing dates between C# and javascript is always going to be hit and miss - we've resorted to using string representations (yyyymmdd) - it's messy, but guaranteed accurate

Comment: Send it to your API as a string. Then convert the string to a Date inside your controller. Of course, continue to use UTC time.

Comment: there's a lot of issues when dealing with js dates. i suggest using a package called "moment.js" and moment.timezone.js to help with the dates and all

Comment: I suffered same issue. Now we used string parameters as its said here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702705/how-to-convert-javascript-datetime-to-c-sharp-datetime

Comment: try converting your date to utc in javascript before sending it to server.

Comment: Yup using strings is what seems to work best. Let c# work it all out