# How to convert/format a date from vb.net to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

In JavaScript, I have dates in an array ( named aLabels) that looks like:

/Date(1485703380827)/,/Date(1485703410233)/,.... to 96 entries.

How to I convert/ format them so I can use them in a label?

I tried:

Looping through the array to try to format each date. But for each iteration, before I am able to modify it, I get: Invalid Date.

```
          // Create a holding array.
          var formatttedDateTime = new Array();

          // Loop thru the label array to format each entry into a formatted data/time.
          for (i = 0; i < aLabels.length; i++)
          {
              var utcDateVal = new Date(aLabels[i]);

              // For testing.
              alert("original date " + utcDateVal);

              var actualDate = new Date(utcDateVal.getTime() + (utcDateVal.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000))

             // Load the formatted date/time array.
             formatttedDateTime[i] = actualDate;
          }
```

Comment: Javascript dates are almost always in the form of milliseconds since 1/1/1970: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20502343/1070452

Comment: Please take care to spell JavaScript properly, avoiding search collisions with Java.