# DateTime Parsing "Wed Mar 12 2014 17:50:15 GMT+0000

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8, datetime-format

I got format exception when trying to parse this

```
// input string "Wed Mar 12 2014 17:50:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
DateTime.Parse(response.LastActivityDate);
```

A first chance exception of type `System.FormatException`

How can I parse it this input string ?
What culture is this ?

thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript date to C# via Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877788/javascript-date-to-c-sharp-via-ajax)

Comment: If you think it is not exact duplicate - check out similar searches - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+javascript+date and update your question with details you still need help with.

Comment: didnt find that sry thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, have some fish:

```
string value = "Wed Mar 12 2014 17:50:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)";
value = value.Replace("GMT","").Replace("(UTC)","").Trim();
value = value.Insert(value.Length - 2, ":");
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```