# Parse Javascript date to C# DateTime, FF data is other then Chrome date

Tags: javascript, c#, date, datetime

I convert javascript date to C# DateTime.

When I use firefox, JavaScript return date to my C# function: 
`string jsDate = "Fri Dec 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100";`

so, I parse it to C# DateTime using:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(JsDate, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Date)
```

When I using Chrome, js return me date in format: `"Fri Dec 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"` (
Central European standard time)

How I can parse the second one time?

Comment: With `TryParseExact`, you have a `DateTime` at the end, not a `string`. That means, you have already a `DateTime` based on your `"Fri Dec 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100"` string. There is no need additional parsing. I don't know what is `Środkowoeuropejski czas stand` but it seems just a additional representation to string representation of your `DateTime`.

Comment: @SonerGönül: I think the point is that the input that Chrome gives is inappropriate for the code - it's not a very clearly written question.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to use milliseconds/seconds as the common base, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1877827/265165

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, sound like that. Not clear question of course, but clearly OP try to using inappropriate string representation of Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't use the default string representation from the browser. Otherwise you need to know which language it's going to use for month names etc, and you're basically fighting a losing battle.

I would strongly recommend that you format the string in a culture-neutral way when you pass it from the browser to the server - e.g. as ISO-8601 such as `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`. You should consider whether or not you need the time zone offset - you may just want to send it in UTC for simplicity. (If you *do* send the offset from UTC, you should probably parse it as a `DateTimeOffset` in your C# code.)

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateString = "Fri Dec 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
dateString = dateString.subStr(0,dateString.indexOf('(')-1);
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Date)
```

Comment: Where did he do the substring of the date string?