# Javascript Date To C# Webservice Error

Tags: javascript, c#, parsing, datetime

I been trying to convert javascript date to c# datetime format to be inserted into microsoft sql database.

This is the codes i currently have:

**Javascript side:**

```
var now     = new Date();
now =  now.toUTCString();
```

**C# side:**

```
//time variable is in DateTime Format

Console.WriteLine("Before: "+time);
String timeString = Convert.ToString(time);

Console.WriteLine("Convert: "+timeString);

DateTime newDT =  DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:FFF",   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine("After: "+newDT);
```

**Error Msg:**

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format,    DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
at -classfile&method name omiited-(DateTime time)
```

**Debug Info:**

```
 Before: 17/8/2015 11:43:48 AM
 Convert: 17/8/2015 11:43:48 AM
```

I'm pretty sure that it is the "timeString" that is inside ParseExact is wrong.

Any ideas on how to solve this ? 
The format of the result i would want would be in this format: 2015-07-27 14:24:23.853 . Thanks!

Comment: Is this in a server method from a web request? If so, what are you getting for data. Is `time` or `timeString` supposed to simulate this? Or am I completely missing the mark? (What is the connection between your JS and C#? How do they communicate?)

Comment: Very unclear what your problem is. It sounds like you've figured out parsing JS date (also your code seem to be not the best one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877788/javascript-date-to-c-sharp-via-ajax) and possibly your question is "how to print DateTime as ISO8601 format"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`17/8/2015 11:43:48 AM` against format `dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt`,and use tostring format

```
DateTime newDT = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("After: "+newDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

Comment: Hi, i would want to convert to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:FFF", any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `toUTCString` function on the `Date` object returns a value in RFC2822 format, such as `"Mon, 17 Aug 2015 05:25:53 GMT"`.  That doesn't align with the `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:FFF"` format you've specified in your C# code.

You have two options.  I recommend the second one.

1. Change the C# code to match the format passed.  The `"r"` standard format matches RFC2822.

   ```
   string s = "Mon, 17 Aug 2015 05:25:53 GMT";
   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "r", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                     DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
   ```
2. Use a clearer format on both side.  I recommend the ISO8601 format for most things.  In JavaScript, use the `toISOString` method to get a date similar to `"2015-08-17T05:25:43.780Z"`.  Then change your C# code to:

   ```
   var s = "2015-08-17T05:25:43.780Z";
   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFZ",
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

## Try this out:- https://dotnetfiddle.net/wLSaYD

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DateParse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var time = "17/8/2015 11:43:48 AM";

            Console.WriteLine("Before: " + time);

            DateTime newDT = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);

            Console.WriteLine("After: "+newDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: newDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") was the one that solved the trick. Thank you so much!