# MVC Button not firing ActionResult with HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am relatively new to MVC and DevExpress. I have a UI where I need to take Date Field and Pass it to Controller. Very Simple task.

My View Looks like.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var positionDate = "1/1/2014";

    function AddClick(s, e) {
        debugger;
        positionDate = LockedDateToAdd.GetDate().toDateString();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/LockedDate/AddLockedDate",
            data: { positionDate: positionDate },
            success: function (msg) { LockedDateGridView.PerformCallback(); }
        });
    }
</script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Locked Dates";
}

<h4>Locked Dates</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(settings =>
                {
                    settings.Name = "LockedDateToAdd";
                    settings.Date = DateTime.Today;
                    settings.Properties.AllowNull = false;
                    settings.Properties.DateOnError = DateOnError.Today;
                    settings.Properties.CalendarProperties.ShowWeekNumbers = false;
                }).GetHtml()
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
                {
                    settings.Name = "LockedDateAdd";
                    settings.Text = "Add";
                    settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "AddClick";
                    settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                }).GetHtml()
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

I am looking to pass Date using AddClick method.

Controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddLockedDate(string positionDate)
{
    DateTime dateValue;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(positionDate, out dateValue))
    {
        _dataAccess.AddLockedDate(dateValue);
    }

    return Content("");
}
```

Issue is, my code is not hitting AddLockedDate ActionResult. When I remove  [HttpPost], it does hit but positionDate comes as empty.

What am I missing here? Any idea. 
Thanks for helping out.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using ? I can't see anything wrong with your code. Have you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980389/proper-way-to-use-ajax-post-in-jquery-to-pass-model-from-strongly-typed-mvc3-vie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when different representation of client-side date from JS which not straightly parseable by `DateTime.TryParse`.

Using `console.log(positionDate)`, the captured date format becomes like this (at the current time of writing):

```
Wed Mar 22 2017
```

The date format is non-parseable using `TryParse` without specifying proper date format, hence use proper formatting with `TryParseExact`:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddLockedDate(string positionDate)
{
     DateTime dateValue;

     // parse exactly as toDateString method returns
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(positionDate, "ddd MMM d yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
     {
         _dataAccess.AddLockedDate(dateValue);
     }

     return Content("");
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var positionDate = "1/1/2014";

    function AddClick(s, e) {
        debugger;
        positionDate = LockedDateToAdd.GetDate().toDateString();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("AddLockedDate", "LockedDate")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) { LockedDateGridView.PerformCallback(); }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Related:

[Javascript date to C# via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877788/javascript-date-to-c-sharp-via-ajax)

[DateTime.TryParse](http://DateTime.TryParse) (MSDN)

[DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) (MSDN)

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto , thanks  for your help. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no issues in your code. Just update ajax method as per below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var positionDate = "1/1/2014";

    function AddClick(s, e) {
        debugger;
        positionDate = LockedDateToAdd.GetDate().toDateString();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/LockedDate/AddLockedDate",
            data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (msg) { LockedDateGridView.PerformCallback(); }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonny. Your suggestion was very helpful. My issue is resolved now.