# Which format controller will take while parsing received JSON date?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am posting JSON Data to my controller. One of the fields contains date. When i send date in MM/dd/yyyy format, the controller is taking dd/MM/yyyy format. Due to this my month is becoming day at server side. If i send 3/20/2017 then it is becoming 01/01/0001 at server side because 20 is not a valid month. How do i force controller to take 3/20/2017 in MM/dd/yyyy format. I initially though iis is referring my system time format. But it did not work even after i changed my system date format to MM/dd/yyyy.

Sample JSON which i am sending to server. Request type is **POST**. (Here i am posting only date field but in my actual request i have other fields too.)

```
{date:"3/20/2017"}
```

### Model:

```
Test{
public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}
```

### Action:

```
ActionResult Demo(Test test)
{
//some code
}
```

Comment: convert your string date to jquery Date() and than pass `date.toISOString()` from jquery ajax method to controller

Comment: None of these. The de-facto standard is ISO8601 :`2017-03-30T07:23:36.933Z`. You can get this from a `Date` object with [Date.toISOString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: BTW you should *always* use ISO8601 when dealing with date literals.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this AJAX call:

```
var date = "3/20/2017";
...
$.ajax({
        ...
        url: '/Controller/Demo',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { date: date },
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
       });
```

In controller side, use `DateTime.ParseExact` to convert date into `DateTime` format:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Demo(String date)
{
    // other stuff
    ...
    var test = new Test();
    test.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    ...
    // other stuff
}
```

To prevent hassles with date formatting, conversion to UTC with `toISOString()` method is more recommended (see [/a/23502790](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502790/6378815) for details):

**View (JS)**

```
var date = new Date("3/20/2017").toISOString();
```

**Controller**

```
test.Date = DateTime.Parse(date);
```